# Convergence rate of $x_{k+1}=3x_k^2/n+3$

Tags: recurrence-relations, quadratics

I've found the following claim in a slightly different form here [(page 4, bottom of the left column)](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/04soda.diam.pdf)

> Starting from $x_0\le n/3$, the recurrence equation
>   $$3\le x_{k+1}\le\left\lfloor3\frac{x_k^2(1+\delta)}n +3\right\rfloor$$ converges to $x_n=3$
>   after $n=\cal O(\log\log n)$ steps.

I've tried to prove this statement but I found on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) that the recurrence equation
$$
x_{k+1}=ax_k^2+bx_k+c
$$
is not solvable in a closed form in general. (Even $x_{k+1}=x_k^2+c$ is not.)

However it is not difficult to convince myself of the soundness of the stated claim: indeed, $x_{k+1}=ax_k^2$ has a solution of the form $x_k=K(ax_0)^{2^k}$. On Wolfram again, the equation $x_{k+1}=x_k^2+1$ starting from $x_0=1$ has as solution $x_k=c^{2^k}$ and $x_{k+1}=x_k^2-x_k+1$ starting from $x_0=1$ has as solution $x_k=d^{2^k}+1/2$.

So it seems realistic to conjecture that when a recurrence equation of the form $x_{k+1}=ax_k^2+bx_k+c$ decreases strictly, it converges to $x_n=1$ in $n=\cal O(\log\log x_0)$ steps.

Is there a result like this?

Comment: Are you saying that it is exactly equal to $3$ after $O(\log\log n)$ steps, or just that it gets within $\epsilon$ of $3$ (where $\epsilon$ is independent of $n$)?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It gets exactly to 3. For some reasons detailed in the paper, in this case $x_k$ cannot go below 3.

Comment: @Ivan That seems strange. Is this an integer-valued sequence or is there some extra rounding going on here? Usually this kind of sequence would have a sort of exponential falloff approaching the limit, like the closed form examples you give, which approach $0$ very quickly but are never equal to it, unless you start at $0$.

Comment: @Ivan Yes it is an integer-valued sequence that decreases strictly at each iteration.

Comment: It seems like the first step of the blockquoted equation will always be increasing, for $\delta\ge 0$, when $x_0=n/3$ and I see no reason for it to ever go back down (assuming it always follows the upper bound).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, that is a mistake in the paper. Imposing $x_{k+1}\le3+3x_k^2(1+\delta)/n\le x_{k}-1$, one finds that $$x_k\le\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-48(1+\delta)n}}{6(1+\delta)}.$$ In fact, this bound on $x_k$ turns asymptotically to $x_k\le n/(3(1+\delta))$.